# Android Studio and regex search (find more words)

Tags: android-studio

I need to find two or more terms within the same file in the project. My guess is that I have to use regex as the search term.

How can I formulate regex to search for "term1" and "term2" for all files in the project?

As I remember IntelliJ support regex search, but I cannot make it work in Android Studio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regex search seems to be fully ported to Android Studio. I have been using it for the last 2 weeks, and so far faced no issues with it.

For those who would like to use regex search for "2 terms in 1 file", they can use the following form `Term1[\w\W]*Term2`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for such a feature in newer android studio versions after 2020.

I can perform a Regex search using this icon

[image: Search by regex]